# error: Element cannot be its own parent

Tags: c#, wpf

Why it isn't working?

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() 
{ 
   Header = new DataGridColumnHeader 
   { 
      Name = eName, 
      Background = Brushes.AliceBlue 
   } 
});
```

The error is:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Element cannot be its own parent.

Comment: Can you show some other code - how you declare, create and work with `dataGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly Header is not a control. It's a content.
You could reach your goal with *HeaderStyle*

```
Style headerStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
headerStyle.Setters.Add(
     new Setter(DataGridColumnHeader.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.AliceBlue));

lb.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
{
     Header = eName,
     HeaderStyle = headerStyle
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the Header should be an object type you are not allowed to add another DataGridColumn type. That is the reason why the exception occurred. You are basically nesting your column which is illegal. It is preferably another control as its content.

For example, this will work based on your code:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
{
    Header = new Button()
    {
         Content = "string",
         Background = Brushes.AliceBlue
     }
});
```

Without the backround or any other UI details, you can actually do:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
{
   Header = "header string"
});
```